# Include API endpoint in web forms website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal, webforms

I'm trying to integrate PayPal with my server.  Here is the guide I'm following:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#on-the-server

It says to make an API call to the server using the following code:

```
createOrder: function() {
  return fetch('/my-server/create-paypal-transaction', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    return data.orderID; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
  });
}
```

Here is the sample they provide, but I can't see any way to make API calls to the methods.  How is it supposed to work?

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/tree/develop/Samples

My website is web forms, will I need to create a separate web API to be able to use this paypal code or can I somehow include an API endpoint within my website project?

Answer (score 0):

That sample code is part of a PayPal JS button that allows the customer to approve an order.

To use that sample code, which is for a server integration (best version [here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)), you need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', each of which is documented nearby on the site you linked: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

These two routes of yours on your server will do anything you need them to do as far as managing your own order records and details, call the PayPal API to create or capture a PayPal order (respectively), and forward the response back to the JS caller.

Comment: How exactly are routes set up?  Do they not have to be API endpoints that the createOrder function I posted above calls?

Comment: Also, the code they provide calls the methods inside Main(), but it will have to be called via javascript (i.e. the code I posted initially)

Comment: The request to and response from your two routes will likely be JSON, so they are essentially API endpoints on your server that serve as middleware to the PayPal API, and add a layer of whatever business logic and server-side order management you need.

Comment: So my initial question still stands:  do I have to create a separate web API to do this or is it possible to do in web forms?

Comment: Adding a Web API would probably be the most natural way to send and receive JSON in your asp.net environment, i.e. something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms , but of course I have no real experience with asp.net and am just helping you search google